# $apply not working within onchange call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a file upload which works, and am trying add a spinner icon to show that the file is being put into memory. The form save/submit button is disabled until the file is fully in memory. Right now I have the spinner working but it broke my button disable

previous HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Image <span class="required_field">*</span>:</label>
    <input class="input-dnld" id="loadImg" type='file' placeholder="Select an image to upload" name="topoImg" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readimg(this)" accept="image/*" required>
    <label for="loadImg" required><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open glyph-style"></span>Select an image to upload</label>
</div>

...

<button ng-click="saveTopo()" ng-disabled="frmNode.$invalid || !image" class="btn btn-default action_btn_style">Save</button>
```

current HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Image <span class="required_field">*</span>:</label>
    <input class="input-dnld" id="loadImg" type='file' placeholder="Select an image to upload" name="topoImg" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().readimg(this)" accept="image/*" required>
    <label for="loadImg" required><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-open glyph-style"></span>Select an image to upload</label>
</div>
<span style="width: 30px">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-spinner fa-pulse" ng-show="imgupload"></i>
</span>

...

<button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="frmNode.$invalid || imgupload ||  !image" class="btn btn-default action_btn_style">Save</button>
```

previous JS function:

```
$scope.readimg = function(ele) {
    $scope.image = ele.files[0];
}
```

current JS function:

```
 $scope.readimg = function(ele) {
    $scope.imgupload = true;
    $scope.$apply();
    $scope.image = ele.files[0];
    $scope.imgupload = false;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

I've added $apply and a boolean variable to show that the image is being uploaded. Before adding the $apply the boolean from the function wasn't being changed until after the function returned. After adding the $apply the spinner shows up but the button is enabled long before the spinner disappears. I tried modifying the condition statement with the boolean value but it doesn't seem to be updating. Because of the lack of ng-change support on file type field in angularjs and me being a beginner at web dev I'm scratching my head how to make this one work.

Comment: When you call the function doesn't the button get enabled immediately because you have imgupload in the if statement

Comment: this is a bizarre set up the ideal would be to create a directive for this. how ever to make it work maybe add a setTimeout ane execute $scope.$apply() in it

Comment: @sebenalern are you talking about the ng-disabled field? I don't see how it would get enabled.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I would like to see an example directive. I've looked into angular modules but haven't found one that works for what I need. If there is a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: create a directive restricted to A, make it isolated scope. attach an internal function the onChange event handler. expose onStart and onFinish events and then execute those functions from within  the directive to notify your current scope of the upload status